# ISERROR in Excel fails when using an array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When using the formula `ISERROR` in Excel, I get unexcepted results when using the formula with an array (in this example A2:A11).

I would like to get all cells in column A evaluated together in one cell (so if just one out of 10 is `FALSE`, then the result is `FALSE`). It shall work as an error-check in a long row of data.

[image: Excel sheet]
[image: Excel sheet with show formula]

Version: Microsoft Excel 2016 (16.0.5413.1000)

Comment: [implicit intersection](https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the @ operator is applicable with dynamic arrays but, from the screenshots provided, where the 'array formulae' only return a single result, it seems that the OP does not have such

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes, I get an array of results too in MS365 which is why I believe the OP is using something older - in the absence of knowing the OP's Excel version, the only area where I can definitively see ISERROR() 'failing' is in respect of the `#DIV/0` error

Comment: Ah there you go man, I understand your points.! Nope it works for `#DIV/0` error as well, could you click on the link i have posted in the first comment

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya _in the OP's screenshot_ (only) the `ISERROR()` function is returning `FALSE` re the `#DIV/0` error, which is what I find anomalous

Comment: @SpectralInstance. Sorry, but I uploaded a version were cell B4 and B5 was switched. It is corrected now.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya and SpectralInstance. Yes, I'm using an older version (2016). An I don't want the result to be an array. I want all entries looked through and if one is FALSE, the result should be FALSE.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya. I do not want to use the drag down option. I only want to get one output, stating if there is any TRUE statements in ISERROR(A2:A11).

Comment: `=SUM(--ISERROR(A2:A11))>0` entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour observed in your screenshots is due to [implicit intersection](https://exceljet.net/glossary/implicit-intersection):
[image: Screenshot illustrating instances of implicit intersection]

with `D3` as the active cell, and the range argument highlighted in the formula bar, it can be seen that the argument resolves to `#NAME`, as it is the content of the cell at the intersection of row 3 (on which this formula resides) and the `A2:A11` range, i.e. cell `A3`.

(the `#NAME` formula-evaluation preview is a feature of MS365, where implicit intersection is no longer standard behaviour, such that the ranges  must be qualified by the '@' prefix to replicate this)

When the same formulae are copied *verbatim* down 11 rows, such that they now lie *below* the `A2:A11` range, they *all* resolve to have a `TRUE` result. The formula in `C15` serves to explain why: these "lower" formula all produce errors (the `#VALUE!` error because none of the rows on which they reside intersect with the `A2:A11` range, meaning that the 'value' passed to the `ISERROR()` function is not a valid value) which the `ISERROR()` functions *all* evaluate as `TRUE`.

As for detecting whether a vertical range of cells is error free, you can use the formula

```
=SUM(--ISERROR(A2:A11))>0
```

entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula), since this will return `TRUE` if *any* cell in the range argument evaluates to an error.

Comment: If I write '=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR(A2:A11))>0' without entered as an array formula will also work. I have office 2016.